# variable outside of while loop becomes NULL when re-assigned

Tags: c++, object, while-loop

Second question I ask about the same program. Does not feel right, but can't help it.

Here's the code that is causing the problem:

```
int main()
{

Link* link = new Link();
Instance* A = new Instance('A');
Instance* B = new Instance('B');
Instance* C = new Instance('C');
Instance* D = new Instance('D');
Instance* E = new Instance('E');
Instance* F = new Instance('F');
Instance* G = new Instance('G');
Instance* H = new Instance('H');
Instance* I = new Instance('I');
Instance* J = new Instance('J');
Instance* K = new Instance('K');
Instance* L = new Instance('L');
Instance* current= new Instance('X');
A->setNearbyObjects(NULL,B,E,NULL);
B->setNearbyObjects(NULL,NULL,F,A);
C->setNearbyObjects(NULL,D,G,NULL);
D->setNearbyObjects(NULL,NULL,NULL,C);
E->setNearbyObjects(A,NULL,I,NULL);
F->setNearbyObjects(B,G,NULL,NULL);
G->setNearbyObjects(C,H,K,F);
H->setNearbyObjects(NULL,NULL,L,G);
I->setNearbyObjects(E,J,NULL,NULL);
J->setNearbyObjects(NULL,NULL,NULL,I);
K->setNearbyObjects(G,NULL,NULL,NULL);
L->setNearbyObjects(H,NULL,NULL,NULL);
string nesw[4] = {"(N)orth","(E)ast","(S)outh","(W)est"};
char choice='X';
current=A;
while((current!=L)&&(choice!='Q'))
{
    current->message();
    cout<<"You can go ";
    for(int i=0;i<current->getPaths().size();i++)
    {
        if(current->getPaths()[i]!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<nesw[i].c_str()<<", ";
        }
    }
    cout<<"or (Q)uit"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    choice=toupper(choice);
    while((choice!='N')&&(choice!='E')&&(choice!='S')&&(choice!='W')&&(choice!='Q'))
    {
        cout<<"Choice: "<<choice<<endl;
        cout<<"Invalid input. Try again..."<<endl;
        cin>>choice;
        choice=toupper(choice);
    }
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 'N':
        current=current->getPaths()[0];
    case 'E':
        current=current->getPaths()[1];
    case 'S':
        current=current->getPaths()[2];
    case 'W':
        current=current->getPaths()[3];
    default:
        break;
    }
}
if(current==L)
{
    cout<<"\n\nYou have found the exit."<<endl;
}
return 0;
};
```

This 'current' variable stores the current object, as you would think. I set it to be object A before I start the while loop. And at the end of while loop, I change it via a case statement to be something else.

The problem is, when the loop goes back to beginning, 'current' becomes NULL. And when I try to call current->message(), it falls over, because there's nothing inside 'current'.

It feels like some basic error I am making here. But I've been bashing my head on this problem for 2 days now and no effect.

Can anyone give me an explanation to what is happening here?

Comment: You reassign `current` in expressions such as `current=current->getPaths()[0];` Whatever value `current` gets depends on what's stored in the `current->getPaths()[0]`

Comment: Yes. And I checked it, at the time of assignment, the getPaths()[0] is not empty and 'current' certainly gets assigned the value of getPaths()[x].

Comment: What's the output of those `cout<<nesw[i].c_str()<<", ";` statements? Do you get all 4, as you're expecting?

Comment: PS: You have a memory leak, since you allocate `Instance* current = new Instance('X')` on the heap but lose the reference before calling `delete` on it.

Comment: from inside the nesw string list. Depending on what 'nearby' objects there are around, it will output something like this:

You can go: (S)outh, (E)ast etc..

Comment: ^Thanks for the memory leak tip. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `break` statement in your choice switch. So it always uses "West" option. The west is NULL in your cell A.